# Text editor that allows for coloring of arbitrary text (and exporting thereof)?

Tags: text-processing, editors

I have a rather large backtrace, which is kind of difficult to read, so I thought I'd color the portions of the backtrace text for easier reading. (I thought, as a backtrace problem, this question is appropriate here - otherwise, admins, feel free to move it to softwarerecs)

Under Linux, I guess, the most immediate option would be to use Open/LibreOffice `writer`; however it:

- Does not give line numbers
- The fonts are not by default monospaced
- Introduces breaks between pages, making the reading more difficult

... although, you can color text easily by selecting the text and choosing a color - and, you can export that coloring to HTML.

What I'd ideally like is a plain text editor like Scite or Geany, having line numbers and a single "page" of text, which will allow for

- arbitrary selection (either through the mouse, or through a regex - implying possibility of multiple selections in the file, e.g. each third word on a line),
- possibility to color that selection, and
- possibility to export that colored/formatted text, either to ANSI-character sequence (so I could view the colored text in terminal, say via `cat` or `less -R`), or to HTML.

Is there any text editor - or alternatively, plugins for existing editors - out there?

Comment: How about `vim` with syntax highlighting and the `TOhtml` function (which also supports ranges)?

Comment: Thanks for that, @Marco - haven't used `vim` much, as I find it a bit difficult (am a `nano` user in the terminal myself), but it's definitely worth a try, now that I have a reference to `TOhtml`; cheers!

Comment: You want your file to be automatically colored, or do you want so manually select some portions of it and set a color to it?

Comment: The title is misleading, since as @Kira says you weren't looking for *arbitrary* coloring but coloring of log files.  For *arbitrary* coloring, see https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3333/4676.

Answer (score 1):

`vim` recognizes certain log file types and will color them once you enable syntax highlighting.  For example, here is gvim showing /var/log/syslog:

[image: gvim showing /var/log/syslog]

You can learn vim with the `vimtutor` command in about half an hour.  You certainly won't master it, and it won't even get into syntax highlighting, but you will learn how to navigate a file and you'll get a hint of its power.

Enabling syntax highlighting should be as easy as `:syntax on`, though you may have to specify the syntax.  The GUI (gvim, [macvim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim#readme), etc.) will have a menu bar with a `Syntax` item.  Tell it to "Show filetypes in menu" (if necessary) and then find the appropriate format.  /var/log/syslog uses the "messages" format (you can also do this with `:set syn=messages`).

#### To output vim's syntax highlighting

Here is my `HTMLize` function, which outputs those colors as HTML, plus the lines to map it to <kbd>F7</kbd>.  Just add these to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
function! HTMLize(...)
  let scheme = "default"
  if (a:0 > 0)
    let scheme = a:1
  endif
  let g:html_use_css = 0
  let oldcolorscheme = g:colors_name
  let oldbg = &background
  execute "colorscheme " . scheme
  set background=light
  TOhtml
  %s/[\r\n]\+//g
  %s/\(color="\|text="\|style="background-color: \)#af0000/\1#b00/ige
  %s/\(color="\|text="\|style="background-color: \)#a52a2a/\1#a22/ige
  %s/\(color="\|text="\|style="background-color: \)#af5f00/\1#a60/ige
  %s/\(color="\|text="\|style="background-color: \)#d7afaf/\1#daa/ige
  %s/\(color="\|text="\|style="background-color: \)#870087/\1#808/ige
  %s/\(color="\|text="\|style="background-color: \)#005faf/\1#05b/ige
  %s/\(color="\|text="\|style="background-color: \)#005f87/\1#068/ige
  %s/\(color="\|text="\|style="background-color: \)#\([0-9a-f]\)\2\([0-9a-f]\)\3\([0-9a-f]\)\4/\1#\2\3\4/ige
  %s/\(color="\|text="\|style="background-color: \)#\([0-9a-f]\)\([0-9a-f]\)\([0-9a-f]\)\3\([0-9a-f]\)\3/\1#\2\4\5/ige
  %s/\(<body \)bgcolor="\([^"]*\)" text="\([^"]*\)">[\r\n]*<font face="monospace">/\1\r\r\r\r<pre style="color:\3;background:\2;width:-moz-fit-content;width:fit-content;border:#dde dashed 1px;padding:.25em">/
  %s/<\/font>\([\r\n]*<.body>\)/<\/pre>\r\r\r\r\1/
  %s/<font color="/<span style="color:/g
  %s/<\/font/<\/span/g
  " %s/<br>$//
  execute "colorscheme " . oldcolorscheme
  execute 'set background = "' . oldbg . '"'
endfunction
noremap <silent> <F7> :call HTMLize("lucius")<CR>
inoremap <silent> <F7> :call HTMLize("lucius")<CR>
```

This is really just a cleaned up version of [`TOhtml`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:TOhtml) that additionally changes your color scheme to make it more legible (I use a dark background with the non-default [lucius colorscheme](https://github.com/jonathanfilip/vim-lucius#readme), which, like the popular [solarized colorscheme](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized#readme), supports both dark and light backgrounds).